# Different sidebars for each Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a Wordpress 2.9.2 theme, and I'd like each page to have its own sidebar than can be edited as easily as the page's content. It would be cumbersome to make a different template file for each sidebar. It would also be weird to add a "custom field" containing all the sidebar text, since I wouldn't be able to use the Visual/HTML editor. What I'd like is to have a  tag similar to the  tag, but instead of delimiting the content to be shown on the front page, it would split the post's content and sidebar. Is this possible? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the sidebars [widgetized](http://www.themelab.com/2008/04/18/see-how-easy-it-is-to-widgetize-wordpress-themes/) and than use the [widget logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin, so you can conditionally include widgets on any and all pages.

Doing this lets you utilize the out of the box widgets, which are awesome, and even integrated third party widgets that are just as great.

Also consider this: You widgetize other areas of your site, like your header, which can now use widgets and widget logic. This makes for a more flexible theme.